# How to merge two images in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have two images:

```
Image frame = new Image();
Image inner = new Image();

frame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/Frame.png", UriKind.Relative));
inner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/Inner.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

I want to merge two images, the inner image at center of the frame.

I couldn't find a `Windows Phone`-specific solution. How can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library has a `Blit` method that does that.

Comment: Isn't there any built-in way? I prefer not to use a third-party library

Comment: The only built-way I see is putting both images in a container control and then render that container control with the WriteableBitmap class. BTW, WriteableBitmapEx is only a set of extension methods that you can add selectively (just browse the source code on the project page and add add the CS files you want). No need to add the entire library.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the code snippet for Blit on the source file, can you help me?

Comment: Here it is: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/WriteableBitmapEx/WriteableBitmapBlitExtensions.cs

Comment: I think nokia imaging SDk also we can use for merging http://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/nokia_apis/imaging.xhtml

Comment: @Mahantesh yes, but it's WP8-only